# How to setup javascript files as :defaults in rails 4?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

My current RoR application using rails 3.2.10 and I want to upgrade it on rails 4.0.0.

I solve the gem dependence but when I run the rails server it give the error :-

```
undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
config/application.rb:39:in `<class:Application>'
```

My config/application.rb file has this code at line 39.

```
#JavaScript files you want as :defaults (application.js is always included).
config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery rails)
```

for that what should do- change the code or remove, any dependence or any other option.

Rails 4 also support assets precompile so I comment the this line:-

```
#config.assets.enabled = true   In rails 4 assets pipline enable by default
```

Comment: I just commented out the `config.act....` in config/application.rb and it fixed that error for me. I am going to look more into it.

Answer (score 3):

if you switch over to using the asset pipeline you should not use javascript_include_tag :defaults any more in your templates, and you don't have to set this configuration option any more.

See the [javascript_include_tag on apidoc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/JavascriptTagHelpers/javascript_include_tag): ""

Comment: ok...when i am not using   config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery rails) / javascript_include_tag then what is other option , because my assets are not working correctly , before that is working fine in 3.2.12

Comment: switching over to the asset pipeline will take some time + some work - but it's absolutely worth it, you get great performance gains!   See http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline?view=asciicast

Comment: @bjelli Gaurav isn't switching over to the asset pipeline. He already uses it in Rails 3.2.10. He is upgrading to rails 4 which has the assets pipeline enabled by default.